# Sort of dictionary values from keys in an ordered list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
FruitValues={'Banana':3, 'Orange':4, 'Apple':1}
```

And I have a list of the keys of this dictionary in a order that I want to preserve:

```
SortOrder=['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

What is the most efficient way of getting a list of the values from the dictionary in the order of the list?

Right now my approach is the following:

```
OrderedValues=[]
for Fruit in SortOrder:
    OrderedValues.append(FruitValues[Fruit])
print OrderedValues

[4, 1, 3]
```

Is there a better / cleaner way of doing this? Maybe using a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> [FruitValues[i] for i in SortOrder]
[4, 1, 3]
```